# Why is Mongoose not allowing me to access the JSON attributes?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In my routes file, I have

```
router.get('/users/:user', function(req, res) {
  mongoose.model('users').find({name: req.params.user}, function(err, user) {
    res.send(user.name || 'User.name is not defined' );
  });
});
```

And my schema is defined as

```
var userDataSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
}, {collection: 'users'});

mongoose.model('users', userDataSchema);
```

In my routes file, if I just do `res.send(user)`, then it gives me the proper JSON back with all of the users with their names.  My problem is that I am not able to access the specific name from the JSON.

I have tried doing `JSON.stringify(user)` and then `JSON.parse()` to that variable, but user.name is still not accessible.  I have now also tried `user.toJSON()`, but this causes an error and does not even respond with 'User.name is not defined'

EDIT: Here is the JSON:

```
[
  {
    _id: "57feb97017910fa7e0e194d8",
    name: "Garrett"
  },
  {
    _id: "57feb97817910fa7e0e194d9",
    name: "Steve"
  },
  {
    _id: "57feb97c17910fa7e0e194da",
    name: "Joe"
  }
]
```

So when I go to /users/Steve and `console.log(user)`, it logs the correct JSON for that user.

Comment: On the server console.log(user.name) prior to sending the response.  What is it logging?

Comment: It logs undefined

Comment: I think you should call method [toJSON](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toJSON)

Comment: var json = user.toJSON();
    res.send(json.name || 'User.name is not defined' );  

This causes an error.

Comment: Since it is logging undefined the only response that will be sent is ''User.name is not defined''.  Try console.log(user) - you may need to JSON.strinigfy(user) first, and see if there is a name property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use .findOne or user object will be array

Comment: Okay, that worked.  That's weird though that the user object is an array.  When I did `typeof user` it said `object`

Comment: So does it return an array because it doesn't know how many names there are going to be?  So based on that, if you specifically say .find().limit(1) then it would know that there is only one name to give.

Comment: array is object in javascript, you need to test Array.isArray(user)

Comment: .find always return array, `For findOne() it is a potentially-null single document, find() a list of documents, ` - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Comment: normally, that user variable should be named like `users` to be clearer.

Comment: That makes sense.  I hadn't realized before that arrays are objects.  Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125551/discussion-between-garrett-smith-and-you).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know what that button did, but I don't actually want to go to chat.

Comment: no worries, I normally dont enter chat rooms either.